# jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am reading my Karaoke list from a DB and that works well but want i want to do is be able to type in a string in a search form and as I type it starts to load songs and/or artists that match.

I know the basics of what I need but not sure on what I need to do the auto-complete?

any help or resource will will be Helpful

Comment: The resource you need is right here. Search for [jquery autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+autocomplete) and you shall find. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419229/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-jquery-autocomplete-options-such-as-mustmatch-highlig)

Comment: as far as i can see thats only bring down a menu you can pick from i want it to update the page as i type kinda like google dose

Comment: So it's not the autocomplete you're actually having an issue with..?

Comment: Aha -that is a matter of adding the data to the rest of the page. Just return JSON and parse it into title and "other stuff"

Comment: ok where can i find some info on json i havent ever used that!

Comment: look it up at jquery autocomplete sample page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Here is an example of how it should be implemented:

```
var AutoCompleteOptions = { source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your URL here',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            itemToSearch: request.term // could be any data you are passing in for search
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something where search values are returned
        },                                  
    });
    }, 
    select: $.proxy(function(event, ui){
        // what you want to do with that information
        // using a proxy to preserve the reference to 'this'
        return false; // prevent the default response (typically inserting the selected value into the textbox the dropdown is being displayed from.
    },this), 
    open: function(event, ui) { 
        // things to do when the dropdown is rendered
        return false; // prevent default autocomplete open action
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        // what to do when an the user hovers over an item in the drop down
        return false; // prevent default autocomplete open action
    },
    minLength:0 // be sure to set this if you want to be able to trigger the search event manually and have it display results
    };

 var Input = $("input");

 Input.autocomplete(this.AutoCompleteOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery autocomplete, Include library and depended files as in the order it should appear
[here is autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

PHP code

```
public function cities() {

    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $cities = array("one","two","three");// contains value fetched from DB
    $filtered = array();
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
      if (stripos($city, $term) !== false) {
        array_push($filtered, $city);
      }
    }
    echo json_encode($filtered);
    exit;
  }
```

jQuery code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#textboxid" ).autocomplete({
      source: "cities",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```